# Android Get dimensions of Image in ImageButton

Tags: android, imagebutton

Is there a way to get the dimensions of the image currently set in the `ImageButton`? I'm trying to achieve this.

I have a `ImageButton` with a default pic of 36 x 36. I then select an image of size say 200 x 200. I wanna call something like:

```
imageButton.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                        bitmap, 36, 36, true));
```

to shrink the image to 36 x 36. Reason why I want to get the original image size is to cater for hdpi, mdpi and ldpi so I can set dimensions of the bitmap to 36 x 36, 24 x 24 and 18 x 18  respectively before adding it to the `ImageButton`. Any ideas?

Oh man, I got the answer after randomly fiddling with the code:

```
imageButton.getDrawable().getBounds().height();    
imageButton.getDrawable().getBounds().width();
```

Comment: You should post the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code -

```
imageButton.getDrawable().getBounds().height();    
imageButton.getDrawable().getBounds().width();
```

Answer (score 2):

Maurice's answer didn't quite work for me, as I would frequently get 0 back, resulting in an Exception being thrown whenever trying to generate the scaled bitmap:

> IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0

I found a few other options if it helps anyone else.

### Option 1

The `imageButton` is a `View` which means we can get the `LayoutParams` and take advantage of the built-in height and width properties. I found this from [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18074835/940217).

```
imageButton.getLayoutParams().width;
imageButton.getLayoutParams().height;
```

### Option 2

Have our `imageButton` come from a Class which extends `ImageButton`, and then override [View#onSizeChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

### Option 3

Get the drawing rectangle on the view and use the `width()` and `height()` methods to get the dimensions:

```
android.graphics.Rect r = new android.graphics.Rect();
imageButton.getDrawingRect(r);
int rectW = r.width();
int rectH = r.height();
```

### Combination

My final code ended up combining the three and selecting the max. I am doing this because I will get different results, depending on which phase the application is in (like when the View has not been fully drawn).

```
int targetW =  imageButton.getDrawable().getBounds().width();
int targetH = imageButton.getDrawable().getBounds().height();
Log.d(TAG, "Calculated the Drawable ImageButton's height and width to be: "+targetH+", "+targetW);

int layoutW = imageButton.getLayoutParams().width;
int layoutH = imageButton.getLayoutParams().height;
Log.e(TAG, "Calculated the ImageButton's layout height and width to be: "+targetH+", "+targetW);
targetW = Math.max(targetW, layoutW);
targetH = Math.max(targetW, layoutH);

android.graphics.Rect r = new android.graphics.Rect();
imageButton.getDrawingRect(r);
int rectW = r.width();
int rectH = r.height();
Log.d(TAG, "Calculated the ImageButton's getDrawingRect to be: "+rectW+", "+rectH);

targetW = Math.max(targetW, rectW);
targetH = Math.max(targetH, rectH);
Log.d(TAG, "Requesting a scaled Bitmap of height and width: "+targetH+", "+targetW);

Bitmap scaledBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, targetW, targetH, true);
```